# Custom Field as Title in Search Results

Tags: search, display-template, managed-property, crawled-property

OnPrem 2013.
I'm looking for a way to use a Custom Field as the Title (clickable link) in results of search. I have dug across the Internet and found many things that got me close. Here is what I tried so far:

- Create Test Site, add custom field to DocLib as single line of text. Added docs and metadata.
- Created sub-site with Enterprise Search template.
- Created Results Set that only returns from DocLib. Tested... works.
- Created a new Managed Property and mapped to Crawled Property ows_CustomField. (even copied options from Title ManProp) Reindexed site, Incremental Crawl.
- Got into copy of Item_CommonItem_Body.html and added ManProp to mso:ManagedPropertyMapping.
- Modified line 20 (as called out in many online articles) and referenced my Managed Property. No Dice.

I am able to switch the Title to other ManagedPropertyMappings already called out in the mapping such as Path, EditorOWSUSER, and more, so I know I'm doing something close. I just don't know why it doesn't like my custom ManagedProp...

For the record, I also tried adding the mapping the ows_CustomField to the 'Title' ManProp, and move it to the top hoping it would take this as the 'first non empty value'. No Dice.

Simply put, these work:

- var title = Srch.U.getHighlightedProperty(id, ctx.CurrentItem,
  "Title");
- var title = Srch.U.getHighlightedProperty(id, ctx.CurrentItem,
  "Path");
- var title = Srch.U.getHighlightedProperty(id, ctx.CurrentItem,
  "DocId");

This does not:

- var title = Srch.U.getHighlightedProperty(id, ctx.CurrentItem,
  "CustomManProp");

Hoping someone can point out what I'm doing wrong.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need add that managed property in item not in commonitem file.
Find what item you want to change (inspect item on search results and find for ex.

```
name="Item" data-displaytemplate="WebPageItem"
```

Then go to

```
YOURSITE/_layouts/15/manageresulttypes.aspx?level=sitecol
```

and create copy of that item.
Add that `CustomManProp` and save file. Go again to

```
YOURSITE/_layouts/15/manageresulttypes.aspx?level=sitecol
```

and clik update in ribbon.

And that's it. :)

---

EDIT

Default Word result type looks at Item_Word.html

Copy of word result type for ex. WordNew make it look at your Item_WordNEW.html

Edit Item_WordNEW.html and add your CustomManProp in `<mso:ManagedPropertyMapping msdt:dt="string">'CustomManProp':'CustomManProp',...`

You can call your property before `_#=ctx.RenderBody(ctx)=#_` (RenderBody uses Item_CommonItem_Body.html to render)

```
<!--#_
    var customManProp = ctx.CurrentItem.CustomManProp;
_#-->
    _#=customManProp=#_
    _#=ctx.RenderBody(ctx)=#_
```

then go to 
`YOURSITE/_layouts/15/manageresulttypes.aspx?level=sitecol` and click update in yellow ribbon to view your custom managed property.

Comment: Hi @eVT, Thanks for the response! I'm still struggling a bit with the details. My items are Word Docs (data-displaytemplate="WordItem"), so made a copy of Item_Word.html file, and pointed to copy of word result type. Now in the html copy file, where am I putting the reference to CustomManProp? Tried mso:ManagedPropertyMapping, but didn't have an impact. (added ,'CustomManProp':'CustomManProp' to the end, and tried 'Title':'CustomManProp') Not seeing anything else intuitive. Thanks!

Comment: go to YOURSITE/_layouts/15/manageresulttypes.aspx?level=sitecol and you click a Property Sync alert.  https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/tothesharepoint/2013/09/06/how-to-display-values-from-custom-managed-properties-in-search-results-option-1/

Comment: This was completed in both tries of: <mso:ManagedPropertyMapping msdt:dt="string">'Title':'CustomColumnProp'... and ...'CustomColumnProp':'CustomColumnProp' with no results.

Comment: Can you be a bit more specific and complete... i.e. CustomManProp to be mapped to CrawledProp, this display template needs this line of code here, etc. Thanks again!

Comment: i have updated answer.